How do I overwrite a string buffer without modifying earlier uses of it
I've recently started learning C, and I'm trying to implement a hash map datastructure.
I'm currently implementing my buckets as dynamically resizing array-backed lists.
When testing my bucket_remove function I made an error in my test code that I'm struggling to understand.
Here is my new_entry function:
struct Entry *new_entry(char *id)
{
    struct Entry *e = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    e->id = id;
    return e;
}

And here is my test_remove function:
static char *test_remove()
{
    struct Bucket *b = new_bucket();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        char id[8];
        snprintf(id, 8, "entry-%d", i);
        struct Entry *e = new_entry(id);
        bucket_add(b, e);
    }

    printf("Entry 0 id: %s.\n", b->_entries[0]->id);
    printf("Entry 1 id: %s.\n", b->_entries[1]->id);

    // ... rest of code omitted for clarity
}

Inside the loop at each iteration, a new entry is created with the correct id, but the previous entries' ids are then updated to the most recent id.
So, the console prints:
Entry 0 id: entry-4.
Entry 1 id: entry-4.

I believe this is related to the way I am passing the local id buffer to my new_entity function. Each entry must be receiving a pointer to the same memory. But I can't quite figure out why this is the case.
This is how I understand the code in the loop:

char id[8]; - memory for 8 characters is allocated in the stack and the address is assigned to id.
snprintf(id, 8, "entry-%d", i); - the pointer to the id buffer is passed to snprintf which fills it with the characters of the created string.
struct Entry *e = new_entry(id); - the pointer to the id buffer is passed to new_entry where a new Entry struct is allocated on the heap and the id (pointer) is assigned to its id member.
bucket_add(b, e); - the pointer to a bucket and the pointer to the entry are passed in to bucket_add and the entry (pointer) is added to the bucket's array of entries.

When a new iteration occurs, it looks like a new section of memory is allocated and its new memory address is assigned to a new variable in local scope. So how does the previous memory get overwritten?
I would appreciate if someone could clarify my understanding, please.

e->id = id; stores the pointer passed, which is to the same local buffer for each entry.

@WeatherVane I considered that that was the case, but isn't the local buffer a new buffer in each loop iteration, as it goes out of scope?

If it goes out of scope, any pointers to it become invalid. You need to make a dynamic copy of the string and store a pointer to that in the hash key.

As a stack item, it's quite likely to be the same address. But as you say, it goes out of scope, so printing the result outside of the loop is UB.

What's likely happening is that each time you call the function, the address of the local buffer is the same.

@WeatherVane AH this makes sense. It hasn't overwritten the original, but the original could now point at anything? And in my case, it happens to reuse the same address that was just made available.

Yes, calling printf() outside of that code block may or may not trash the data. If not, all the entries will point to the most recent data.

Thanks, both. If someone would like to write up an answer describing that a dynamic copy must be made and stored instead of the local buffer, I can accept the answer.

@Barmar: Re “If it goes out of scope, any pointers to it become invalid”: That is not the rule. In static void foo(const char *p) { puts(p); } int main(void) { const char a[] = "Hello, world."; foo(a); }, a is not in scope in foo, but a pointer to it is still valid.

When the array goes out of scope it is de-allocated, thus available for reuse. On most real compilers, because of the way they allocate memory, the next id array gets the exact same piece of memory.

@EricPostpischil a has not gone out of scope in your example. It wasn't, and isn't in the scope of function foo(), but is still in the caller's scope.

The TL;DR: The caller of new_entry always passes the same value for id. To fix this, in new_entry, change e->id = id; into e->id = strdup(id);

@WeatherVane, I think Eric would prefer terminology along the lines of "when execution of the innermost block containing the definition of id terminates, any pointers to it become invalid."  If he's in a particularly prickly mood then he might even insist on "become indeterminate".  He is technically correct, though we all knew what Barmar meant, probably even the OP.

@JohnBollinger: I do not know why people think students will be able to resolve inaccuracies or ambiguities. Where would the information needed to determine the correct meaning come from? The nature of studying means that one does not yet have desired information. Some particular student might happen to have enough information to resolve the problem in one case, but certainly some will not. One should assume it is necessary to make correct unambiguous statements to students.

Thanks to the comments to my question, I now understand the issue.
The error I have is a "stack use after scope" error. This error occurs when a pointer to memory in the stack is used after the scope in which the memory was allocated ends.
In the code below I have created a buffer char id[8] in the for loop, giving it local scope within the block. This means that not only does id go out of scope at the end of each iteration (which most programmers recognise from other programming languages), but, crucially, the underlying memory itself is also marked as available.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    char id[8];
    snprintf(id, 8, "entry-%d", i);
    struct Entry *e = new_entry(id);
    bucket_add(b, e);
}

In each iteration of my for loop, a new 8 bytes is requested from the stack and assigned to a new variable with local scope called id. My compiler reuses the 8 bytes on the stack that were just made available from the previous iteration, so id is given the same memory address on the stack as the previous iteration. This is implementation specific though, it may not always work this way.
This in itself is fine and expected as the normal rules for scoping. The error occurs because I take the pointer to stack memory id and copy this pointer in to heap memory here:
struct Entry *new_entry(char *id)
{
    struct Entry *e = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    e->id = id;
    return e;
}

The compiler has no problem with a pointer in the heap pointing to memory on the stack. But it becomes an error when this pointer on the heap is used to access the memory in the stack after it goes out of scope and becomes available for reuse. This is undefined behaviour, which means we risk memory corruption, or pointing at unintended memory.
So, when I accessed the data outside of the local scope in which it was declared:
printf("Entry 0 id: %s.\n", b->_entries[0]->id);
printf("Entry 1 id: %s.\n", b->_entries[1]->id);

The output:
Entry 0 id: entry-4.
Entry 1 id: entry-4.

The undefined behaviour manifested itself as every entry in my bucket having an id pointer to the same memory location, and thus the same value. This would get worse the later the pointer was used because this memory would be overwritten again shortly.
This problem is resolved by ensuring when a pointer needs to outlive its scope, that the underlying memory it points to *also outlives its scope. In my case, it means I need to copy the string that id points to, to heap memory and save the new heap address instead.
I've chosen to use the strdup function to do this:
#include <string.h>

struct Entry *new_entry(char *id)
{
    struct Entry *e = (struct Entry *)malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    e->id = strdup(id);
    return e;
}

The output shows that the error is resolved:
Entry 0 id: entry-0.
Entry 1 id: entry-1.


You passe a pointer to new_entry(char *id)
For the computer that create on the stack a variable with the memory address of the id string.
When you do e->id = id; in new_entry() you save in e->id the memory address of the id string and not the string.
When you re-call snprintf(id, ...); you re-write the string, save in your char id[8];.
And when you read your id's you read a pointer to the char id[8], and you read the last change you make.
We can check it with printing the pointer address of all the element id :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Entry
{
    char *id;
};

struct Entry *new_entry(char *id)
{
    struct Entry *e = malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    if (e == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    e->id = id;
    return e;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Entry * b[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        char id[8];
        id[0] = '0' + i;
        id[1] = '\0';
        struct Entry *e = new_entry(id);
        if (e == NULL)
            return (-1);
        b[i] = e;
    }

    printf("Entry 0 id: %s.\n", b[0]->id);
    printf("Entry 1 id: %s.\n", b[1]->id);
    printf("Adress 0 id: %p.\n", b[0]->id);
    printf("Adress 1 id: %p.\n", b[1]->id);
    free(b[0]);
    free(b[1]);
    return (0);
}

Resulting in that output :
➜  test ./a.out
Entry 0 id: 1.
Entry 1 id: 1.
Adress 0 id: 0x7ffd7496bd30.
Adress 1 id: 0x7ffd7496bd30.

We have tow time the same address so to time the same string.
We also have a problem because char id[8] is not in the stack anymore at the print.
And that can create some stack corruption :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Entry
{
    char *id;
};

struct Entry *new_entry(char *id)
{
    struct Entry *e = malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    if (e == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    e->id = id;
    return e;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Entry * b[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        char id[8];
        id[0] = '0' + i;
        id[1] = '\0';
        struct Entry *e = new_entry(id);
        if (e == NULL)
            return (-1);
        b[i] = e;
    }

    char test[8];

    test[0] = ';';
    test[1] = '\0';
(void)test;

    printf("Entry 0 id: %s.\n", b[0]->id);
    printf("Entry 1 id: %s.\n", b[1]->id);
    printf("Adress 0 id: %p.\n", b[0]->id);
    printf("Adress 1 id: %p.\n", b[1]->id);
    free(b[0]);
    free(b[1]);
    return (0);
}

Resulting :
➜  test ./a.out
Entry 0 id: ;.
Entry 1 id: ;.
Adress 0 id: 0x7ffc08207880.
Adress 1 id: 0x7ffc08207880.

If you want to save a copy of the string you need to call strdup (duplicate a string) or strcpy (copy a string) :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Entry
{
    char *id;
};

struct Entry *new_entry(char *id)
{
    struct Entry *e = malloc(sizeof(struct Entry));
    if (e == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    e->id = strdup(id);
    if (e->id == NULL)
    {
        free(e);
        return (NULL);
    }
    return e;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Entry * b[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        char id[8];
        id[0] = '0' + i;
        id[1] = '\0';
        struct Entry *e = new_entry(id);
        if (e == NULL)
            return (-1);
        b[i] = e;
    }

    printf("Entry 0 id: %s.\n", b[0]->id);
    printf("Entry 1 id: %s.\n", b[1]->id);
    printf("Adress 0 id: %p.\n", b[0]->id);
    printf("Adress 1 id: %p.\n", b[1]->id);
    free(b[0]->id);
    free(b[1]->id);
    free(b[0]);
    free(b[1]);
    return (0);
}

Resulting :
➜  test ./a.out
Entry 0 id: 0.
Entry 1 id: 1.
Adress 0 id: 0x556eb8f522c0.
Adress 1 id: 0x556eb8f52300.

Also casting your malloc() is generally a bad idea.
And don't forget function call like malloc() or strdup result need to be free() and can fail and is your responsibility to handle it.

Hi Von, thanks for your answer. It looks like the first part needs clarifying though. Specifically this bit:
"When you re-call snprintf(id, ...); you re-write the string, save in your char id[8];.
And when you read your id's you read a pointer to the char id[8], and you read the last change you make."
This sounds like the memory is overwritten because I reused a pointer, whereas technically I didn't. I actually got a new pointer, but because the old pointer and its underlying memory went out of scope and were deallocated, I was reassigned the same pointer address again...

... So, although it looks like I reused a pointer, it is implementation specific, and is actually undefined behaviour.
The rest of your answer is very good though, so thanks!
